# prevent popup-box to open in kendo grid

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I want to stop opening popup-boxes in some cases. I mean on specific condition i should open and sometimes it shouldn't in Kendo Grid. I am using javascript and jquery for this. I am using js 1.7.1 of kendo.

```
$('.k-grid-Add').on("click", function () {
if(val==-1)
{
                alert('Please select agent');
//here i want to prevent popup-box
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false;`

```
$('.k-grid-Add').on("click", function (e) {
if(val==-1)
{
  alert('Please select agent');
  return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grid.find("div.k-grid-header").find("div").find("table thead tr").find('th').each(function () {
   $(this).find('.k-filter').click(function () {
   $(this).css("display","none");
   });
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Please explain it.